# In Ionic 3 how can i add number of days to date?

Tags: angular, date, ionic3

```js
  ionViewDidEnter() {
    let self = this;
    self.originationsProvider.getOrigination()
      .then((data) => {

        self.origination = data;
        console.log(self.origination, "slefOrigination");
        this.complete = self.origination.filter((obj) => obj.state_status == 'completed');
        this.inComplete = self.origination.filter((obj) => obj.state_status == 'not_completed');
  
  // i am getting Change_Date from self.origination json
        console.log(this.inComplete, this.complete, "Incomplete");
        self.servicing = data;

        self.cdr.detectChanges();
      })
  }
```

```html
                    <p style="white-space: initial;font-size: 15px;color: #3f454e;">Proxy payment due by: “No Later than {{account.Change_Date}}”</p>
  
  //I am getting date in Change_Date.I have to display the date by adding 9 days to it.
```

I want to add 9 days to today's date. I am using Angular 4 & Ionic 3.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var today = new Date();
```

Add 9 days to date

```
var nextdate = new Date(today.getFullYear(),today.getMonth(),today.getDate()+9);
```

Comment: Thanks @kuldeep its working now..Also i found another way of doing it by using moment...https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment-business-days